# Fixing incorrect server scheme in URL input

Tags: regex, url

I'm accepting web address input from a form, however some URL's are formatted incorrectly like this (dont ask):

```
http:/www.foo.com
ftp:/ftp.bar.com
scp:/meh.foobar.com
```

What I want to do is detect if only one forward slash is present and add a second one.

I've never been any good at regular expressions, so I tried it with a combination of substr and parse_url to pick out the scheme, then strip it. But it was a bit of a mess and stripped valid URL's adding a triple /// in the scheme and taking out letters from the hostname in some cases.

Help please :)

Answer (score 1):

use this regular expression: `'.*:/[a-zA-Z].*'`

it will be matches with:

```
http:/www.foo.com
ftp:/ftp.bar.com
scp:/meh.foobar.com
```

and do not matches with:

```
http://www.foo.com
ftp://ftp.bar.com
scp://meh.foobar.com
```

then replace your invalid characters using replace(i dont know what language you are using):

```
url = myUrl.replace(url,':/','://')
```